# How can I say that not noticing something was very difficult?

Tags: phrase-request

How can say that something was very difficult not to be noticed?

I was thinking of the opposite of "I could barely notice that." on the lines of "I could not not notice that." which doesn't seem correct (too much *not* in row). Is there a better way to say what I am trying to say?

Comment: I could not help but notice that ... COLLOQUIAL VERSION: I couldn't help noticing that ...

Comment: '...could not not' doesn't work, but couldn't not is used in conversation: "Your eyes must be good. How did you notice that car?"  "Whaddaya mean? I couldn't not notice it.  It's a Ferrari."

Comment: "If it was a snake it would have bit you!" ;) This is actually a common phrase, but have warning that it should be used only to joke around with someone you know well.  Otherwise someone could take offense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the word *help* is inserted to convey this thought:

> I couldn't *help but notice* that ketchup on your chin.

The leading words can vary; one might say *I can't help but notice*, or *he couldn't help but notice. Cannot* and *could not* are sometimes used as well.

You can find several instances of this phrase if you peruse [this list](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22help%20but%20notice%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1970,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en).

[An Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help%20but%20notice&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) would suggest that this particular wording is relatively contemporary, at least in terms of its popularity:

[image]

Comment: Can I reply with "I could not help but noticing it" to somebody who asks me "How did you notice that detail on that car?"

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, but either remove the 'but' or change noticing to notice.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that this something was [glaring](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glaring), [blatant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blatant) or [flagrant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flagrant).

Or "I couldn't help noticing that", as was suggested in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

There is an idiom that something obvious is *as plain as the nose on your face.* [It is defined as:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+as+plain+as+the+nose+on+your+face)

> to be very obvious -- *There's no doubt that he's interested in her. It's as plain as the nose on your face.**

Answer (score 1):

You could say it was *clearly visible* or that *it was right in front of you.*

Answer (score 0):

For completeness and if you don't mind resorting to the, ahem, slightly less formal:

> It sticks/stuck out like dogs' balls

is quite common in this part of the world with a tally of 113 on [this list](http://www.sunburntcountry.au.com/sayings/aslist.html) (warning: explicit language)